# Stuck with collision detection in circle pong in xna

Tags: c#, xna

I am making clone of Circle pong game in xna. I am not able to get collision of rotating pad with ball. I can't use farseer physics in this game as it is in mono game.

I found one method for it but it also not seem to work.

```
    private void EllasticCollisionPhysics(Ball ball, GoScreen pad)
    {
        //find normal vector

        Vector2 normal = new Vector2(pad.padV.X - ball.ballRectangle.X, pad.padV.Y - ball.ballRectangle.Y);
        //find normal vector's modulus, i.e. length
        float normalmod = (float)Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(normal.X, 2) + Math.Pow(normal.Y, 2));

        //find unitnormal vector
        Vector2 unitnormal = new Vector2((pad.padV.X - ball.ballRectangle.X) / normalmod, (pad.padV.Y - ball.ballRectangle.Y) / normalmod);

        //find tangent vector
        Vector2 unittan = new Vector2(-1 * unitnormal.Y, unitnormal.X);

        //first ball normal speed before collision
        float inormalspeedb = unitnormal.X * velocity.X + unitnormal.Y * velocity.Y;

        //first ball tangential speed 
        float itanspeed = unittan.X * velocity.X + unittan.Y * velocity.Y;


        //Calculate normal speeds after the collision



        //Calculate first ball Velocity vector components (tangential and normal)
        Vector2 inormala = new Vector2(unitnormal.X * inormalspeedb, unitnormal.Y * inormalspeedb);
        Vector2 itana = new Vector2(unittan.X * itanspeed, unittan.Y * itanspeed);

        //Add Vector components to each balls' Velocity
        velocity = Vector2.Add(inormala, itana);
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having exactly?

Comment: I am not able to detect collision with rotating paddle and moving ball

Answer (score 0):

You don't need farseer physics for that, what you need is circle to rectangle collisition funciton.

```
// circle is object with x,y,r parameters
bool intersects(CircleType circle, RectType rect)
{
    circleDistance.x = abs(circle.x - rect.x);
    circleDistance.y = abs(circle.y - rect.y);

    if (circleDistance.x > (rect.width/2 + circle.r)) { return false; }
    if (circleDistance.y > (rect.height/2 + circle.r)) { return false; }

    if (circleDistance.x <= (rect.width/2)) { return true; } 
    if (circleDistance.y <= (rect.height/2)) { return true; }

    cornerDistance_sq = (circleDistance.x - rect.width/2)^2 +
                         (circleDistance.y - rect.height/2)^2;

    return (cornerDistance_sq <= (circle.r^2));
}
```

Added CircleType and RectType

```
public class CircleType
{
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public decimal r;
}

public class RectType
{
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public int width;
    public int height;
}
```

Comment: is this circletype is used in Box2D??

Comment: i'm not familiar with Box2d, added classes of CircleType and RectType. This can be used anywhere, it's just math function that check collision between circle and rectangle.

Comment: actually i was using rectangle for collision but the problem is that rectangle are not moving with objects. and as physics is not used direction of ball after collision is also not perfect.